# Twisted: spawn an application daemon from another application daemon

Tags: twisted, twisted.application

I have a Twisted application daemon which is started by twistd. This daemon acts as a daemon manager to manage  many other Twisted application daemons. I can send the manager a "new" command via TCP and the manager should spawn(fork) another Twisted application daemon. My question is how can I do that? After fork, I think I should stop the manager's reactor loop, close opened file descriptors(logging file), then run the new Twisted application daemon. I want to know the details of how to do these things properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the reactor's `spawnProcess` method.  See http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/process.html for details on its use.

You should not fork or do any of those other steps yourself.  They are difficult to do correctly, and `spawnProcess` already does them for you.

If you're curious about how these things are done, you can browse the [various](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/posixbase.py) [implementations](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/_dumbwin32proc.py).

Comment: You mean: reactor.spawnProcess(p, 'twistd', ['twistd', '-ny', 'anotherApplication.py'], {})

Comment: Sure, something like that.  The exact parameters no doubt depend on the exact behavior you're after.